# Using a checkbox to loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a program where data is being filled into a listbox. When I click a checkbox to loop, it should loop from the very beginning. When I click the checkbox it does not check and it also prevents me from clicking anything else because of the infinite loop. Does anyone know a solution around this?

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while(checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: WinForms?  ASP.NET?  Something else?

Comment: I think you need to use if block instead of while block. I am guessing your loop is in Play() method.

Comment: But I need to loop it so why would I use an If?

Comment: @MalloryRich under what circumstances does the `checkBox1.Checked` become `false` again?

Comment: When the box is checked it should loop, when the box is unchecked it should stop looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need Play to execute on a background thread or you need to pulse the windows message pump so give the UI time to react to input. This is the latter:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while(checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        Play();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

[DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) causes windows to process any messages (like UI input) that are currently in the message queue. Without it, windows messages are never processed because Play is on the UI thread and the message pump never has a chance to run, so even if you are furiously clicking on the checkbox, windows never has a chance to tell your app about it.

There are a lot of ways to do this with Play on a background thread. Those examples are a little bit more involved than the message pump approach of DoEvents.

- [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [System.Threading.Tasks.Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [System.Threading.Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx)

Bare in mind that multi-threading is more of an advanced approach that can be harder to implement correctly, though is something worth understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I did a Task Parallel Library (TPL) based implementation. TPL is now the defacto multi-threading paradigm recommended by Microsoft. Specially TPL is best at keeping your UI responsive while doing other work in background. Here is the code snippet for the same:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            //iterate list box items on a thread-pool thread using TPL
            Task.Run(() => Play());
        }
    }

    private void Play()
    {
        //listBox1 is the name of the list box control in my windows forms application
        foreach (var listboxItem   in listBox1.Items)
        {
            //check if the checkbox is currently in checked state
            if(checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                //Checkbox is checked so process the listbox item
                Console.WriteLine(listboxItem.ToString());
                //do other required stuff
            }
            else
            break;    
        }

    }
```